# The Azure PowerShell session has not been properly initialized. Please import the module and try again

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm writing my first powershell script to load data from a CSV to an Azure Storage table. I'm not sure why the line

```
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName)[0].Value
```

is throwing an error:

[image]

Running `Get-Module` gives this result:
[image]

This is a snippet of the code that I have written till now:

```
# Step 1, Set variables
# Enter Table Storage location data 
$resourceGroupName = "ComputeTesting"
$storageAccountName = 'computetestingdiag'
$tableName = 'strtable'
$dateTime = get-date

# Step 2, Login to your Azure subscription
$sub = Get-AzSubscription -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if(-not($sub))
{
    Connect-AzAccount
}

# If you have multiple subscriptions, set the one to use
# Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "<SUBSCRIPTIONID>"

# Step 3, Get the access key for the Azure Storage account
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName)[0].Value

# Step 4, Connect to Azure Table Storage
$storageCtx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storageCtx
```

I checked some of the similar questions and what I understand that uninstalling and re-installing the Azure modules might help. Although I didn't try this yet, is there any other workaround for this? Any help whatsoever would be highly helpful.

Comment: Please try to use `New-AzStorageContext` to replace `New-AzureStorageContext`.  Your step 1and 2 use Az module but your step3 use AzureRm module. The two modules may cause conflicts in the same Powershell session

Comment: Perfect! This works absolutely fine! Indeed, I mixed up Az and AzureRM modules..Thank you!

Comment: I post my suggestions as a solution. Since it is helpful for you, could you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the script you provided, you use the `Az` and `AzureRM` modules at the same PowerShell session. It may cause conflicts. I suggest you use the one module in one session.

For example

```
$resourceGroupName = "<>"
$storageAccountName = '<>'
$tableName = '<>'

Connect-AzAccount
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName)[0].Value

$storageCtx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$table = Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $storageCtx
```

For more details about how to manage Azure table storage, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell)